# ImmutableJS in Redux : Uncaught TypeError: oldArr.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I have this reducer:

```
import Immutable, { Map, Record} from 'immutable'
const tags = Map({ primary: ['tag1','tag2','tag3'], secondary: [] });

export default function (state=tags, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
      case 'ADD_PRIMARY_TAG': {
        //not sure about this:
        var oldArr = state.get('primary');
        var newArr = oldArr.push(action.payload)
        var newState = tags.set('primary', newArr);
        return newState;
      }
      default:
        console.log("Default Tags Reducer.");
      return state;
    }
}
```

However, I am not sure about this. So i have an immutable Map and there I have an array called `primary`, which contains some tags. Now I would like to add a tag to the existing array. So I get the current array with `state.get('primary');`, I push something into a copy of it, and then I set the new state to the new array and return it.

I don't see where I am going wrong, or whether I am using Immutable the wrong way maybe.

When i run this I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: oldArr.push is not a function
>       at exports.default (index_bundle.js:44134)
>       at combination (index_bundle.js:32954)
>       at dispatch (index_bundle.js:18293)
>       at index_bundle.js:44171
>       at Object.addPrimaryTag (index_bundle.js:32975)
>       at PhraseView.tagsSubmit (index_bundle.js:33813)
>       at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (index_bundle.js:6380)
>       at executeDispatch (index_bundle.js:4920)
>       at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (index_bundle.js:4943)
>       at executeDispatchesAndRelease (index_bundle.js:3439)
>       at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (index_bundle.js:3450)

Is the way I am using Arrays here (in the context of ImmutableJS) maybe completely wrong? Shoudl the Arrays in my Immutable Map be other immutable objects? Or how does this error come about?

Comment: `push` mutates an array

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=b) instead of `push()`.

> The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

Change:

```
var newArr = oldArr.push(action.payload);
```

To:

```
var newArr = oldArr.concat([action.payload]);
```

Comment: That was my first thought too, but I just tried the code from the example and it should work, if there's an array there.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the following and it passes:

```
import Immutable, {Map} from 'immutable'

describe('immutable tests', () => {
  it('Immutable array', () => {
    const tags = Map({ primary: ['tag1','tag2','tag3'], secondary: [] });
    let oldArr = tags.get('primary');
    oldArr.push('blabla')
    expect(oldArr).toHaveLength(4)
  })
})
```

Are you sure the incoming state is what you expect it to be? Maybe it has some other structure, from the stacktrace it's not very clear what invokes your reducer